# how to send dropdown item to controller not the value ,which is populated using ajax

Tags: asp.net-core

this is my ajax code to get the dropdown item and send to controller in response it also populate another dropdown,
this dropdown item is not being sent to controller but id is sent.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#ddtname').on('change', function () {
               var ctname = $("#ddtname").find("option:selected").text();
               var selectedValue = $("#ddtname").val();
               alert("Selected Text: " + ctname + " Value: " + selectedValue);
               $.ajax({
                    url:'@Url.Action("Getdata","ConfigClass")',
                    type: "GET",
                     data: {'ctname':ctname},
                   dataType: "text",

                    //Response carry bunch of data from controller
                     success: function (response) {
                         alert(response);

                         //parse json obj to js
                         var obj = JSON.parse(response)
                         var ele = document.getElementById('sel');
                         $('#sel').empty();

                         //append default value to dropdown
                         var s = '<option value="-1">SubjectName</option>';

                         //using loop for populating dropdown ,values retrive through ajax
                         for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                             // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
                            s+='<option value="' + obj[i]['aid'] + '">' + obj[i]['assignsubject'] + '</option>';
                         } 
                         $('#sel').html(s);
                   },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('not working :(');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

this is my dropdown form

```
<Select class="form-control" id="sel" placeholder="" name="csub">
  <option selected="selected">Subject Name</option>
 </Select>
```

This is my model

```
public class ConfigClass
    {
         [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string ctname { get; set; }
            public string cclass { get; set; }
           public string csub { get; set; }
           public string csec { get; set; }
           public string ctime { get; set; }
            
        
    }
```

As i submit my form i get the subject id not the name or item of dropdown how do i bind so that i get the item not the value in the controller side

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get subject name when form post,you can change

```
s+='<option value="' + obj[i]['aid'] + '">' + obj[i]['assignsubject'] + '</option>';
```

to

```
s+='<option value="' + obj[i]['assignsubject'] + '">' + obj[i]['assignsubject'] + '</option>';
```

If you want to get both subject id and name when form post,you can use a hidden input to save subject name.Before form posting,set input value to the selected subject name.
Here is a demo:

View:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <Select class="form-control" id="sel" placeholder="" name="csub">
        <option value="-1">SubjectName</option>
        <option value="0">Maths</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>
        <option value="2">History</option>
    </Select>
    <input hidden id="subjectName" name="subjectName" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
<script>
            $('#myform').submit(function () {
                $("#subjectName").val($("#sel").find("option:selected").text());
                // DO STUFF...
                return true; // return false to cancel form action
            });

    </script>
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestDropDown(ConfigClass c, string subjectName)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]